# Swift 4 - Creating a multiple choice quiz using a Struct - Major flaw

Tags: swift, xcode, struct

I am creating a quiz using a `struct` in Swift. For the most part, everything functions/works as intended. However, after a certain amount of questions my answers (only the 2nd and 4th answer) would switch places. So the fourth answer becomes the second answer, and the second answer becomes the fouthr answer (on the user interface and in my code). And example of this would be

This is my struct:

```
struct Question {
    var Question: String!
    var Answers: [String]!
    var CorrectAnswer: Int!
}
```

My code would look like such:

```
 Questions = [(Question: "What colour is the sky?",    
              Answers: ["Pink", "Blue", "Gold", "Green"],
              CorrectAnswer: 2)]
```

However, this is how the question and answers would be displayed on the UI -

```
What colour is the sky? 
    A) Pink
    B) Green
    C) Gold
    D) Blue
```

And due to the `CorrectAnswer` equalling `2` you would have to select `Green` or else you'd get the question wrong. They only way to rectify this would be to change `CorrectAnswer` to `4` so it now doesn't follow the struct.

Have I done something wrong?

This is what the rest of my code looks like:

```
  var Questions = [Question]()
    var QNumber = Int()
    var answerNumber = Int()


    func generateRandomQuestion() {
        if Questions.count > 0 {

            QNumber = 0
            questionLabel.text = Questions[QNumber].Question
            answerNumber = Questions[QNumber].CorrectAnswer

            for i in 0..<ButtonsCollection.count {
                ButtonsCollection[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
            }

            Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

        }

        else  {


         print("Done")

        }
    }
```

I don't wish to manually go through all the questions individually to test and amend where needed as I have over 1,000 questions to go through if that is the case. Where have I gone wrong? And is there a much easier way to go about inserting all my questions?

Thank you.

Comment: what is buttonCollections. im pretty sure it cells, the get reused and boom ui changes ;) the struct wont randomly change

Comment: Just an outlet collection of all my buttons. This helps to set and display all the answers. But it's only the second and fourth button that is affected. 1 and 3 are perfectly fine.

Comment: an outlet collection isnt safe regarding order ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually not a good idea to depend on the ordering of the items in an outlet collection, because that is something that is hard to verify.  Although, I'd be surprised if the ordering changes over time.

How about using the `tag` property of the buttons?  Go into the Storyboard and assign tag `0` to your first answer button, tag `1` to the second answer button, and tag the last two `2` and `3`.

Then change your loop to:

```
for button in ButtonsCollection {
    button.setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[button.tag], for: .normal)
}
```

This will assure that no matter what order your buttons are in in the outlet collection, the right answer will be assigned to the right button.

Comment: Also, by convention in Swift, variable names, property names, tuple labels should start with a lowercase letter.  So `buttonsCollection`, `qNumber`, and `answers`.  Type names such as `Question` should remain capitalized.

Comment: @iSwift, did that help?

Comment: Sorry bud. My brain was fried from all the coding yesterday. Just implemented it and it works a treat! Thank you so much. I have accepted your answer. Once again, thank you.